# C# linq with two Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm stuck at the following Problem:
I want to load one List, but I can pass more than one Parameter what could be the criteria to find the Lists I want.
Now I have the following structure:

```
House{
  Name;
  ID;
  Alias;
}
```

Also I Have:

```
Person{
  Name;
  Alias;
}
```

This means, 1 house can hold multiple persons and multiple persons with the same name can be in multiple houses.
So now I want to call my Function e.G. "GetHouses(string criteria)" as criteria could be:

1. a Name of a house
2. an ID of a house
3. a part of the name of the house
4. a Name of one of the Persons in the house

Now I just read every house and it's data and I select afterwards by the criteria.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: I can not change the logic until here!**

So now as I try to find the matching criteria I came up with using LINQ as it is very fast. It works as long as I don't compare to the Persons:

```
result = (from x in result
where (
  (string.Equals(x.Name, criteria))
  || (string.Equals(x.ID, criteria))
  || (x.Name.Contains(criteria))
  select x).ToList();
```

Now I want to load every Person to the houses I found and check if a Name of the Persons in the house would match the criteria.
Is there a way to do this within the LINQ I have already?
Or do I have to go though the result with:

```
result.ForEach(x => ...)
```

Would be nice if it would work with the LINQ.
I did a similar Logic with the

```
result.FindAll(new Predicate<House>((x) => { ... LoadPersons(criteria) {... } }));
```

But that took to long.

Kind regards,
Asat0r

Comment: have you not just tried linking the two items in linq? rather than a foreach

Comment: How is the house related to the person? Do you want to "load" the persons into the matching houses that have the same matching criteria? If so, what if one person could match into multiple houses?

Comment: Shouldn't House class hold in it a list of persons?

Comment: I don't want to "load" the persons to the house, as they are already in the house. I just want to find every house that holds a Person with the Name given in the Criteria. e.g: house 1 holds: Ann, Peter, Jack, John. house 2 holds: Jason, Jeff, Jared, Jack. Now if i call "GetHouses("Jack")" it should return List<Houses> { house1, house2 }; as if I call it with "GetHouses("Ann")" it should only return a List with house1. No need for a List<Person> in the houses either.

Comment: How can a house hold a person, if there is no reference to person in the house class? Do you keep both in a dictionary? Could you post the code, where person is assigned to house?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you have a `PersonList` in your `House`-class you could use `Enumerable.Any`:

```
var matchingHouses = from house in allHouses
    where string.Equals(house.Name, criteria) 
       || string.Equals(house.ID, criteria) 
       || house.Name.Contains(criteria)
       || house.PersonList.Any(resident => string.Equals(resident.Name, criteria))
    select house;
```

If you have a method to return the "residents" you can use this. If you later want to access these persons you could create an anonymous type to store them:

```
var housesAndResidents = from house in allHouses
    let matchingResidentList = LoadPersons(house.ID)
       .Where(resident => string.Equals(resident.Name, criteria))
       .ToList()
    where string.Equals(house.Name, criteria) 
       || string.Equals(house.ID, criteria) 
       || house.Name.Contains(criteria)
       || matchingResidentList.Any()
    select new { house, matchingResidentList };
```

You can access these properties in the following way:

```
var matchingHouseList = housesAndResidents.ToList(); 
// you don't need the list, you can use foreach directly,
// but whenever you access housesAndResidents you will execute that query
// ToList materializes this query into a collection, so you can enumerate it or use the Count property
foreach(var x in matchingHouseList )
{
    Console.WriteLine("House:{0} Matching-Resident(s):{1}"
        , x.house.Name
        , String.Join(", ", x.matchingResidentList.Select(r => r.Name)));
}
```

Comment: Well that gave me an Idea, even though I don't have a List in the House class, the method "LoadPersons()" returns a List of Persons, so I added:
" || LoadPersons(x.ID).Any(y => string.Equals(y.Name, criteria))"
As I can only load Persons if I use the ID of a house. But this also takes some times.

Comment: @Asat0r: for sure it takes some time because this query is every costly, but i don't see how you could improve it. We know too little about the background to suggest anything better.

Comment: @Asat0r: i have shown a second approach which uses the method and stores it in an anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) if it doesn't get any faster than this is the way I do this :) helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using three classes: `Program`, `House` and `Person`.

The class `House` "houses" (pun intended) a list of the class `Person` (and your own values: name, id and alias). In this way the residents are a part of the house and not stored somewhere else. Storing the residents outside the `House` class is the same as having your lunchbox's contents outside the box in your backpack.

The class `Person` stores the basic information about the house's residents. Having a list of residents inside the `House` class makes it easier to compare the search criteria with the people.

In the class `Program` you'll find the `Main` and the `FindHouses` classes. These kinda explains themselves

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public string alias;

    public Person(string _name, string _alias = "")
    {
        name = _name;
        alias = _alias;
    }
}

class House
{
    public string name;
    public string id;
    public string alias;
    public List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    public House(string _name, string _id, string _alias = "")
    {
        name = _name;
        id = _id;
        alias = _alias;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static List<House> houses = new List<House>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Add houses here

        foreach (House house in FindHouses("criteria"))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    // Find all the houses in which the criteria exists
    static List<House> FindHouses(string criteria)
    {
        // Return the list of all houses in which the criteria exists
        return houses.Where(h =>
            h.name.Contains(criteria) ||
            h.id == criteria ||
            h.alias.Contains(criteria) ||

            h.people.Any(p => 
            p.name.Contains(criteria) ||
            p.alias.Contains(criteria))).ToList();
    }
}
```

I dont know if this is too big of a change in your code, but anyways, I hope this helps.

I know you mentioned you didn't want to load the persons into the houses, but this makes the search for houses based on "all values" much easier